# How can I validate a password based on my rules?

Tags: php, regex

I have three rules:

- at least 6 characters
- it should be containing both digit(s) and letter(s)
- signs are acceptable like `$`, `@`, `^`, `&`, `*` etc ...

How can I do that?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
if ( preg_match($password, "/([0-9]|[a-zA-Z]){6,}/") ) {
    // password is valid
} else {
    // password isn't valid
}
```

**Note1:** being capital or lowercase letters doesn't matter.

**Note2:** starting with whatever doesn't matter.

---

Here is some acceptable examples:

```
urj2fr
948ff4k
#gk4%rg45
f9493^#0
kf94k39f43
```

Here is some unacceptable examples:

```
frki5       // length problem
gerkewkgr%  // lack of digit problem
```

Comment: Downvoter please leave a comment and explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: I upvote because I think your question is legit, but we should know which programming language you are using. thanks. and did you get any error messages ?